# Get total amount for each month in a year

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE MONTH(str_to_date(sm.BillDate, '%d/%m/%Y')) WHEN 1 THEN sm.GrandTotal ELSE 0 END) AS 'January',
SUM(CASE MONTH(str_to_date(sm.BillDate, '%d/%m/%Y')) WHEN 2 THEN sm.GrandTotal ELSE 0 END) AS 'February',
SUM(CASE MONTH(str_to_date(sm.BillDate, '%d/%m/%Y')) WHEN 3 THEN sm.GrandTotal ELSE 0 END) AS 'March',
SUM(CASE MONTH(str_to_date(sm.BillDate, '%d/%m/%Y')) WHEN 4 THEN sm.GrandTotal ELSE 0 END) AS 'April',
SUM(CASE MONTH(str_to_date(sm.BillDate, '%d/%m/%Y')) WHEN 5 THEN sm.GrandTotal ELSE 0 END) AS 'May',
SUM(CASE MONTH(str_to_date(sm.BillDate, '%d/%m/%Y')) WHEN 6 THEN sm.GrandTotal ELSE 0 END) AS 'June',
SUM(CASE MONTH(str_to_date(sm.BillDate, '%d/%m/%Y')) WHEN 7 THEN sm.GrandTotal ELSE 0 END) AS 'July',
SUM(CASE MONTH(str_to_date(sm.BillDate, '%d/%m/%Y')) WHEN 8 THEN sm.GrandTotal ELSE 0 END) AS 'August',
SUM(CASE MONTH(str_to_date(sm.BillDate, '%d/%m/%Y')) WHEN 9 THEN sm.GrandTotal ELSE 0 END) AS 'September',
SUM(CASE MONTH(str_to_date(sm.BillDate, '%d/%m/%Y')) WHEN 10 THEN sm.GrandTotal ELSE 0 END) AS 'October',
SUM(CASE MONTH(str_to_date(sm.BillDate, '%d/%m/%Y')) WHEN 11 THEN sm.GrandTotal ELSE 0 END) AS 'November',
SUM(CASE MONTH(str_to_date(sm.BillDate, '%d/%m/%Y')) WHEN 12 THEN sm.GrandTotal ELSE 0 END) AS 'December'
FROM
  sales_master sm
WHERE
  YEAR(str_to_date(sm.BillDate, '%d/%m/%Y'))='2017'
GROUP BY 
  MONTH(str_to_date(sm.BillDate, '%d/%m/%Y'))
```

I am working with MySQL where I need the total Amount spend each month for a given year (If for a given month there is no amount spend then it should print Zero).
The above query does exactly what I need but I get the total values in separate rows.
I need something like for all the months all the value should come in one single row. So that I can read easily.
[image: Result I get]

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in your application code

Comment: @Strawberry I didn't get what you are trying to say

Comment: You have PHP, so use that, and not sql, for formatting your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close.  Just remove the `GROUP BY`.

You should not be storing dates as strings.  On rare occasions, that is necessary.  But I would advise you to fix the type format, so the date is stored as a date.

Second, you can simplify the logic using `like`.  If you have strings, use string operations:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN sm.BillDate LIKE '%/01/%' THEN sm.GrandTotal ELSE 0 END) AS January,
       . . .
```

Third, `YEAR()` returns an integer, so the comparison should be to an integer.  However, given that the value is a string, just do:

```
WHERE BillDate LIKE '%2017'
```

Or, as mentioned earlier, fix your data so you are storing dates using the proper data type.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon It worked. However, why it was not working before? Is it because I am already grouping the months with the CASE statements and there is not need to explicitly group them again.

Comment: @Roneetshaw . . . The `GROUP BY` was describing a result set with a separate row for each month.

Comment: I know changing the data type is something I should have done earlier. But now I have come very far :(. Next time I will keep in mind.